# What does the "m" mean in Proxmox CPU Usage?

Tags: proxmox

In Proxmox 3.4-6, on the y axis of the CPU usage chart, sometimes it shows an "m" after the number. What does the "m" mean? Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milli or one thousandth.

So a CPU usage of 0.3 would show as 300 m